# Error adding certificate to cacerts. Unknown key spec

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool

I am using jdk 1.6 in Windows. I have a .der file (DER Encoded X509 Certificate) that will like to add to my cacerts file... so I tried the following:

keytool -import -keystore  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -trustcacerts -alias  openldap -file "C:\cacert.der"

I got the following error:
**java.security.cert.CertificateParsingException: java.io.IOException: subject key, java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown key spec**

At first, I thoght it was a problemen with the der certificate, but then doing the following I got exactly the same error:

keytool -list -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre\lib\security\cacerts"

Any ideas why is this problem appearing? I have not found anything in the Web.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You may have two or more jdk's installed on your machine. One thing, which you can try, is go to your target jdk. In your case it is

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin
```

Then run your command, Once it is working, then make sure that your PATH variable is configured properly to the targeted JDK's bin.

Comment: thanks bro ,worked like a charm for me .
Although i have only one jdk (11 version ) ,i don't  know why i face the problem ,thanks you so much

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue while  opening cacert for listing the certificates.
There was a file permission issue  on my machine.
I tried with root user.It was working.
I resolved error by adding new jdk jre with proper permission.